# Thread-managed objects not entering a stack on another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Follow-up on a previous question I posted about a combat simulator.

The problem here: 'Creature' objects do not enter the stack on the 'Combat' class.

The whole thing is several classes larger but I've managed to narrow the problem to the following code.

```
public class Combat implements Runnable {
int Turn = 0;
HashMap<Integer, Faction> Factions = new HashMap<Integer, Faction>();   
Stack<Creature> stack;

public int getFactionsStanding() {
    int Result = 0;

    Iterator<Faction> F = Factions.values().iterator();

    while(F.hasNext()) {
        if (F.next().getMemberCount() > 0)
            Result = Result + 1;
    }

    return Result;
}

public HashMap<Integer, Creature> getEnemies(int factionID) throws NoFactionsException {
    HashMap<Integer, Creature> targetPool = new HashMap<Integer, Creature>();

    Iterator<Faction> F = Factions.values().iterator();

    if (!(F.hasNext()))
        throw new NoFactionsException();

    Faction tempFaction;

    while (F.hasNext()){
        tempFaction = F.next();

        if (tempFaction.getfactionID() != factionID) 

            targetPool.putAll(tempFaction.getMembers());                
    }

    return targetPool;
}

private int getMaxInit(){
    int Max = 0, temp = 0;
    Iterator<Faction> I = Factions.values().iterator();

    while(I.hasNext()){
        temp = I.next().getMaxInit();
        if (temp > Max)
            Max = temp;             
    }           

    return Max;
}

public int getTurn() {
    return Turn;
}

public void setTurn(int turn) {
    Turn = turn;
}

// TODO I can't get creatures to enter the stack! :@
synchronized public void push(Creature C){
    stack.push(C);

    System.out.println("Creature " + C.getName() + " is now on the stack");

    if (C.getInit() == this.getMaxInit())
        this.emptyStack();

    notify();
}

// TODO The stack must be processed now: everyone does what they intended to do
public void emptyStack(){
    Creature C;

    while (!(stack.isEmpty())){
        C = stack.pop();

        C.takeAction();
    }

    Turn = 0;       
}

synchronized public void increaseTurn(){
    this.Turn = Turn + 1;

    System.out.println("Current initiative score is " + this.getTurn());

    notifyAll();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }

}


    public void run(){
    while(this.getFactionsStanding() > 1){
        increaseTurn();
    }
}
}

public class Creature extends Observable implements Runnable {

        synchronized public void declareAction(){
    try{
        if (Combat.getTurn() != this.getInit())
            wait();                 

        Combat.push(this);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        return;
    }
}

public void takeAction(){
    Attack(this.Target, this.leftHandWeapon);

    if (this.Target.getCurrentHP() < 0)
        this.Target = null;
}

public void setTarget() {
    Integer targetID = -1;
    HashMap<Integer, Creature> targetPool;
    Object[] targetKeys;

    try{
        targetPool = Combat.getEnemies(FID);

        if (targetPool.isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyTargetPoolException();

        targetKeys = targetPool.keySet().toArray();

        if (targetKeys.length == 0)
            throw new EmptyTargetKeysArrayException();

        if (this.Target == null) {
            do{
                targetID = (Integer) this.getRandom(targetKeys); //(Integer)targetKeys[(Integer) this.getRandom(targetKeys)]; 
            } while (!(targetPool.keySet().contains((Integer)targetID)));

            this.Target = targetPool.get(targetID);
        }
    }
    catch (EmptyTargetPoolException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (EmptyTargetKeysArrayException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void run() {
    // This will go on and on as long as this creature is alive
    while (this.currentHP > 0) {
        try {
            this.setInit();

            this.setTarget();

            this.declareAction();                       
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }       

    System.out.println(this.Name + " was killed!");     
}
```

}

Comment: These classes are not thread-safe at all!

Answer (score 0):

Does the creatures name get printed out? If so there may be a problem with:

```
if (C.getInit() == this.getMaxInit())
    this.emptyStack();
```

I'm not sure what the method getInit() does but if getMaxInit() also returns the same value then it could just empty the stack each time push() is called. Its the only problem I can see right now that could happen.

Comment: GetInit() returns an integer value representing the initiative score of a creature (e.g., how quickly it reacts). The highest-scoring creature is supposed to enter the stack last AND act first.

Comment: Can't see the problem. My advice would be to go back and test each method to ensure it does what you think it does. Its the only way to narrow down the problem, otherwise I would be guessing.